# Why is the saml issuer duplicated

Tags: saml-2.0

I am not quite understanding the rational behind something in the saml2 spec.

The Saml `Respose` Tag has an optional `Issuer` child, where as the `Assertion` has a mandatory one.

Why is the Issuer in two places, and is it valid for the value to be different?

If the values are different which one takes precedence?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would think there is a case where the entity responding i not the same as the one actually asserting the identity.

Regarding precedence, its a matter of what you are validating. If you are checking that you got a response from the right entity then you check the issuer in the response.

If you already have done this and are now establishing the identity of the user, you use the issuer in the assertion.

Ofcourse, most of the time these will be the same.